# Netbeans open only one project

Tags: netbeans

Is there a way to set Netbeans to open a specific project or only one project or no projects from the list of projects made when you start netbeans?Because it takes very long every time to open all my project,but also I don't want to delete the project I want them to remain there but not to be opened when I start netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question so not sure if you still care or are still looking for an answer. I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.1 and you can manage what projects are displayed at any given time using **Project Groups**

To open the Groups Manager right-click anywhere in the Projects window and select **Project Groups...**

Create a new **Free Group** and make sure **Automatically Save Project List** is checked

Within the Projects Window close any projects that you are not using. Next time you start up NetBeans they will not be there.

To view all your projects again simply open the Groups Manager and select **(none)**

Answer (score 0):

If you rightclick your project and then chose close, the project will be closed and there for not be opened on next startup. Also the project remains on your harddrive.

There is no way to tell netbeans to open a specific project on startup. It opens always the projects that were opened on last close.